# Converting all rows from a CSV file to columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I was able to format my data the way I wanted. After that and with the partial code below, I filled up a matrix with "0"s or "1"s based on output wanted . The problem I have now is with the print statement. Instead of getting a simple output "0011000..." I am getting {(0, 13): ***0***, (1, 13): ***0***, (2, 13): ***1***, (3, 13): ***1***, (4, 13): ***0***, (5, 13): ***0***, (6, 13): ***0***............. How do I get rid of the "extra" symbols "(,{,(,)" and the rows an col positions?  Thanks so much

```
pixels = {}
if on_off == "1":
   pixels  [row, col] = 1                                      
else:
   pixels[row, col] = 0
print(pixels)
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish. What are the columns in your desired output?  Can you show your expected result in dataframe/table form? And clarify how the values in the input file should map to the output.

Comment: Ah, I see, you are trying to transpose rows into columns. Still not sure what "out of the 640 columns, some of the columns, not all, have been extracted" means though.

Comment: the work flow is to read the file/transpose_matrix/write_transposed_to_file. I would like to read every row and turn it into a column. To give you an idea the row is point to the quarter hour, but I want the row to be pointing to the half hour- rotating an eintire row 45 degrees.

Comment: Yes, I removed all unwarted pixels from columns to avoid not needed data and to downsize the files. For this reason, out of the 640 colums I only use the ones with good data

Comment: I think you mean rotate 90 degrees.

Comment: To clarify the idea of unwanted pixels, lets say I gave a  red 100x100 square over a blue background, I would only need all the columns where the "good" pixels are, the ones with the rectangle  and I will discard the rest.

Comment: Yes, 90 degrees

Comment: I think I found a solution but I don't know how to materialize it. Workflow. Step 1. Mark the "unwanted pixels" from each column row by row by using loop for x in range(0, width) :      for y in range(0, height):. (Already done).     Step 2 Then, switch loop to  for x in range(0, height) :
               for y in range(0, width):   Step 3, Write the csv file with latter loop. I will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in range(0, h):
    for y in range(0,w):
         vertical_line = vertical_line +  str( pixels[x][y])
print(vertical_line)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.